# Magento1 website Security patch installation by script

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, install-script, script

Magento1 my website i have installing following Security patch:
Security patch 10975
Security patch 10415
Security patch 9767
Security patch 8788
Security patch 7405
  but i want script in my root folder then run above Security patch.

so i want script.

So help me.

Thank you,
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya

Comment: Do you have any specific reason as you want to execute it as script? The script must be in PHP or shell?

Comment: yes sir i want script in php file

Comment: Straightaway you need to execute all patches or you want to input patch name and then execute it

Answer (score 0):

You can use that `shell_exec` in php file

like that

```
$output = shell_exec('/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.1.1.sh');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($output); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: below error show when run the file form the url like  eample :http://www.mywebsite.com/applypatch.php                                                         
    then below error display                                                                               
   ERROR: "/app/etc/" must exist for proper tool work.